# Pipeline Function in Oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

From the below query I am trying to insert into a table SRC_PK_COLUMNS (Sequence_no,pk_key), where the function returns TABLE type. But this expecting a single row. How to handle this error.

```
 INSERT INTO SRC_PK_COLUMNS (pk_key)
    (SELECT * 
      FROM TABLE(parse_comma_delimited(( SELECT SOURCE_COLUMNS 
                                         FROM RULES_TABLE 
                                           WHERE RULE_NAME = RULE_NAME ), ','))  );
```

1. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this syntax

```
insert into TAB (COL1, COL2, COL3)
select C1, C2, C3 from OTHER_TAB;
```

that is, without the `select` statement enclosed in paranthesis. This way, each selected record will be inserted as well, as opposed to your syntax with the paranthesis where, indeed, only one record is expected.

Note: the inserted and selected columns need to agree in number (and "convertable" datatypes). Therefore, in order to fill `Sequence_no`, too, the statement becomes

```
INSERT INTO SRC_PK_COLUMNS (sequence_no, pk_key)
    SELECT rownum, t.*
      FROM TABLE(parse_comma_delimited(( SELECT SOURCE_COLUMNS 
                                     FROM RULES_TABLE 
                                       WHERE RULE_NAME = RULE_NAME ), ',')) t;
```

Maybe, you want to use a sequence instead of `rownum`.

Comment: The table function returns only one column, but when i dint mention the column name in insert statement it expecting the other column to insert which is sequence number, for that reason i mentioned. The TABLE function returns only one column with multiple rows, that i want to insert into a table.